# Change a style property with Jade html language?

Tags: javascript, css, html, pug

With the code below, written in jade, I thought I would be able to change the div id="content" just by referencing it's ID and then setting a new style.  When I view the results of running this code in my browser however, the content is visible instead of being hidden.  Can someone give me some insight into what I am doing wrong and how to correctly achieve hiding an element like so?

```
   extends layout

    block content
      #content
        h5 good content test

    script.
        var searchVis = "visibility:" + search || "visibility:hidden";
        var uploadVis = "visibility:" + upload || "visibility:hidden";
        document.getElementById("content").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried your jade markup just now, the script fails because you have not declared the `search` or `upload` variables. You can see this error if you use your F12 dev tools in your browser.

The following works just fine for me with Jade 1.3.1:

```
extends layout

block content
  #content
    h5 good content test

  script.
    var search="";var upload="";
    var searchVis = "visibility:" + search || "visibility:hidden";
    var uploadVis = "visibility:" + upload || "visibility:hidden";
    document.getElementById("content").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Comment: Awesome, I was able to see what I had done wrong.  It appears that where the 'script.' is placed is quite significant.  If I placed it at any other indentation it would not work as I intended.  Thanks!